# What is the meaning of well-defined (excitation) spectrum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fermions, many-body

I am studying the Luttinger liquid model of 1-d Fermion systems. I regularly come across the phrase "the low energy excitations are well-defined", but I don't know what it means exactly.
EDIT: You asked for reference. The review article is here http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9510014, I am attaching the a picture.
[image: fig1]

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) To facilitate answering, you might consider adding references ...

Comment: Without references it's difficult to be sure, but a statement of this kind sometimes means that the excitations in question are long-lived, i.e. they do not decay quickly. In particular, their linewidth $\hbar\Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is the decay rate, must be much smaller than their energy.

Comment: @Sanya: Thank you  :)  I have added an edit. May be that will help.
Mark: Yeah you are right, I think I was on the right track. But still from a theoretical perspective how exactly are they defined?